# Rig - Custom Properties - how to create a switch between 2 custom properties

Tags: rigging, customization

I am trying to create  a switch between 2 custom properties.

Context,
I would like to create a switch  or limitation where, if one custom properties is in the value of 1, the others properties will automatically be value of 0.

[image]

In the image, there are two custom properties, as you can see both of the value is 1. I would like to make it if blue is 1, red will be 0 and vice-versa.  Is that possible?

The blender file
[image]

Comment: Do you want to be able to change both custom properties so that each might flip the other, so, for instance I could flip either red or blue to 1 forcing the other to 0; or do you want one to be modifiable but the other be always set by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add 3 custom properties:

Red, Blue and Master

Blue copies the value of Master as Driver

Red gets 1-abs(Master) as Driver

Result:

[image]

blend file:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the replied. I would have never imagine to do it this way but I will try it out. Just curious about the "flip_fluid" custom properties though, I don't really understand about it. My apologize if I sounded amateurish.

Comment: It‘a from my flip fluids add-on. You can ignore that. I am amateur too…but still learning 

Comment: If my answer works for you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.